# sapjco3.dll already loaded in another classloader error

Tags: java, wildfly, jco

I'm using SAP JCo to connect to SAP system from a WildFly 11 server. First I create a war using it and it work. Then I create another ear and after deployment both not working. The error code is below.

> 2020-04-29 08:52:46,433 INFO  [org.directwebremoting.log.accessLog] (default task-74) Method
> execution failed: : java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: JCo initialization failed with
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library D:\BPM\sapjco30\sapjco3.dll already loaded in another`
> classloader

I did some research and found the error may caused by including `sapjco3.jar` in deployment assembly. So I remove the jar from assembly and put it in the `standalone\deployments` folder.

Then I create a `Jboss-deployment-structure.xml` as below and put it in the `WebContent\META-INF` folder for both project.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <!-- Make sub deployments isolated by default, so they cannot see each others classes without a Class-Path entry -->
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <!-- This corresponds to the top level deployment. For a war this is the war's module, for an ear -->
    <!-- This is the top level ear module, which contains all the classes in the EAR's lib folder     -->
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
        <!-- This allows you to define additional dependencies, it is the same as using the Dependencies: manifest attribute -->
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.nana-app.ear" export="true" />
            <module name="deployment.sapjco3.jar" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
        <!-- These add additional classes to the module. In this case it is the same as including the jar in the EAR's lib directory -->
        <resources>
        </resources>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This time another error appeared

> ```
> 2020-04-29 16:46:03,093 INFO  [org.directwebremoting.log.accessLog] (default task-42) 
> Method execution failed: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize
> class com.sap.conn.jco.JCo
>   at com.sap.conn.jco.JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(JCoDestinationManager.java:77)
>   at com.SCOfetch.JCOtest.step4QueryTable(JCOtest.java:264)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule$1.doFilter(CreatorModule.java:172)
>   at org.directwebremoting.impl.CreatorModule.executeMethod(CreatorModule.java:184)
> ```

```
Looks like server can't locate the Jco this time. I guess it's the issue of my Jboss xml. Then what's the correct format? Can someone help? Thanks.
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am facing a similar issue.